# Using either a java call, or Google scripts, can I open a Google doc AND run an installed add-on?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-docs-api

When an end-user clicks on a button in Java, a file is uploaded to google drive and opened in the browser.  Is there a way to make an add-on run automatically as well?  Maybe through the use of a stand-alone gScript app that calls the add-on?  Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as long as the add-on is already installed on the file. You can rely on the triggers in app-script to do so. For example, you can use the onOpen() trigger to add custom menu to a spreadsheet:

```
    function onOpen() {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
    }
```

You can find more information on the appropriate trigger you may require here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/index

Comment: As I stated, this process starts by clicking a button which uploads a file.  The user will have the addin installed for gDocs, but it will not be installed on the file.  My other (untested) option may be to upload the document to a specific folder and instead of calling the file, I'll call a standalone script that launches the most recently added file with the add on triggered. This would be an ugly hack though.